# Strategy | No data returned with no explanation (no error while compiling)

Tags: pine-script

It is my first test of building a strategy with pine script.

I have learned from other public strategies available in TradingView.

Everything seems to be ok with the code with the compiler which returns no error. I enter the parameter, time range of the test etc., but No data is returned.

I have of course searched in stackoverflow, found a post concerning this No Data issue, but could not apply the fix to my strategy, since not applicable.

Honestly, I am a little bit confused, I have 5 days experience in coding with pine script, so I don't really know where to start the debugging.

Would appreciate some help to lead me in the right direction.

Thanks, cheers, Marc

```
//@version=5
// 
// INPUTS

// Time Duration for BACKTEST
fromDay = 5
fromMonth =12 
fromYear = 2021

toDay =  26
toMonth =1 
toYear = 2022

startDate = timestamp(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, 00, 00)
finishDate = timestamp(toYear, toMonth, toDay, 00, 00)
time_cond = time >= startDate and time <= finishDate


//Trading Time

//AOM=input.bool(true,'Follow',inline = "00")//,group="ENTRY EXIT TIME" )
i_sess = input.session("0000-2345", "Trading Time",inline = "00")//,group="ENTRY EXIT TIME")
tradingTime = time(timeframe.period, i_sess)

onMarket=false

if(time == tradingTime )
    onMarket:=true

onMonday=input.bool(true,'Monday',inline = "01",group="TRADING DAY SETTINGS")
onTuesday=input.bool(true,'Tuesday',inline = "02",group="TRADING DAY SETTINGS")
onWednesday=input.bool(true,'Wednesday',inline = "03",group="TRADING DAY SETTINGS")
onThursday=input.bool(true,'Thursday',inline = "04",group="TRADING DAY SETTINGS")
onFriday=input.bool(true,'Friday',inline = "05",group="TRADING DAY SETTINGS")

TradeToday= false

if ( onMonday==true and dayofweek ==2 ) or  ( onTuesday==true and dayofweek ==3 ) or ( onWednesday==true and dayofweek ==4 ) or ( onThursday==true and dayofweek ==5 ) or ( onFriday==true and dayofweek ==6 )
    TradeToday:= true

// === LOGIC ===
length = input.int(defval=14, minval=1, title='Length')
longOnly = input(defval=false, title='Long Only')
fast = ta.ema(50, length)
slow = ta.ema(200, length)
plot(fast, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), title='Fast')
plot(slow, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), title='Slow')

longEntry = ta.crossover(fast, slow)
shortEntry = ta.crossunder(fast, slow)

plotshape(longEntry ? close : na, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.new(color.green, 0), location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, title='Long Triangle')
plotshape(shortEntry and not longOnly ? close : na, style=shape.triangledown, color=color.new(color.red, 0), location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, title='Short Triangle')
plotshape(shortEntry and longOnly ? close : na, style=shape.xcross, color=color.new(color.black, 0), location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, title='Exit Sign')

// LONG POSITION EXECUTION
enterLong = ta.crossover(fast, slow)
exitLong = longOnly and ta.crossunder(fast, slow)
if (time_cond== true and enterLong and onMarket and TradeToday)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
if (exitLong)
    strategy.close("Long")
// SHORT POSITION EXECUTION
enterShort = not longOnly and ta.crossunder(fast, slow)
exitShort = false
if (time_cond== true and enterShort and onMarket and TradeToday)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
if (exitShort)
    strategy.close("Short")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `ta.ema()` function wrong.

```
fast = ta.ema(50, length)
slow = ta.ema(200, length)
```

The first argument is `source` and the second one is `length`.

You are passing 50 and 200 as source which is not correct. Change it to something like below and it will work:

```
fast = ta.ema(close, 50)
slow = ta.ema(close, 200)
```